# C++ to many errors. How to fix?

Tags: c++

I've taken a beginners class in C++ programming and love it, so much that I've been teaching myself the chapters that are covered in the second class. So far the material is not complex-functions, arrays, vectors. However, I was working on a problem from the book and it required that I fill two string vectors with information from two different text files each containing a list of strings-including names with spaces. I ran my code and worked fine for first one. I used the same approach for the second text pull and got some errors.

I've never ran into something like this, so I'm not sure what this means. I get 20 errors and it says that it's stopping now. This is not letting me compile any other programs. How can I fix this?

I've copied and pasted this output below. Also can someone please explain this to me to learn more about these errors.

Thanks!!

This is my first time posting a questions here, sorry for the confusion. 
I did minor fixes to the code I submitted.

My question: my getTeam function worked properly when outputting what it pulled from the text file. But then I outputted the getWinners vector, is when I saw this error occur. Another thing to note is the second file contains 2 empty rows of the list of team winners, this is intentional. I've added the code I've added the code below along with the error I see in XCode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int teams=15;
const int  winning_teams=24;

void getTeams(vector<string> , const int);
void getWinners(vector<string>, const int);

int main()
{
    int count;
    vector<string> names;
    vector<string> winners;

    getTeams(names, teams);
    getWinners(winners, winning_teams);

    for(count=0; count<teams; count++)
        cout<<names[count]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
void getTeam(vector<string> names, teams)
{
    int count;
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("/Users/Desktop/Teams.txt");

    for(count=0; count<teams; count++)
        getline(inputFile, names[count]);
    inputFile.close();
}
void getWinners(vector<string> winners, win_teams)
{
    int count;
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("/Users/Desktop/WorldSeriesWinners.txt");

    for(count=0; count<winning_teams; count++)
        getline(inputFile, winners[count]);
    ifstream.close();
}


















CompileC /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o Ch7\ Continued\ Alone/main.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Desktop/Class_Assignments/2nd class my study/Ch7 Continued Alone"
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Desktop/Class_Assignments/2nd\ class\ my\ study/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone/main.cpp -o /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ch7_Continued_Alone-bkufqcslkavkjzajreyppcxdsdgr/Build/Intermediates/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Debug/Ch7\ Continued\ Alone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o

In file included from /Users/franciscoavalosjr/Desktop/Class_Assignments/2nd class my study/Ch7 Continued Alone/Ch7 Continued Alone/main.cpp:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1674:1: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
.
^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1393:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_pointer'
        {return iterator(get_pointer());}
                         ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1396:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_pointer'
        {return const_iterator(__get_pointer());}
                               ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1399:26: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_pointer'
        {return iterator(__get_pointer() + size());}
                         ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1402:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_pointer'
        {return const_iterator(__get_pointer() + size());}
                               ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1431:31: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_long_size'
        {return __is_long() ? __get_long_size() : __get_short_size();}
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1431:51: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_short_size'
        {return __is_long() ? __get_long_size() : __get_short_size();}
                                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1435:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_long_cap'
        {return (__is_long() ? __get_long_cap() : __min_cap) - 1;}
                               ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1600:79: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_pointer'
    const value_type* data() const _NOEXCEPT  {return _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(__get_pointer());}
                                                                              ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1603:60: error: use of undeclared identifier '__alloc'
    allocator_type get_allocator() const _NOEXCEPT {return __alloc();}
                                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1776:18: error: use of undeclared identifier '__align_it'
                 __align_it<sizeof(value_type) < __alignment ?
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1776:50: error: use of undeclared identifier '__alignment'
                 __align_it<sizeof(value_type) < __alignment ?
                                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1817:17: error: use of undeclared identifier '__alloc'
            if (__alloc() != __str.__alloc())
                ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1822:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '__alloc'
            __alloc() = __str.__alloc();
            ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1850:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '__alloc'
            __alloc() = _VSTD::move(__c.__alloc());
            ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1934:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__zero'
    __zero();
    ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1945:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__zero'
    __zero();
    ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1958:15: error: use of undeclared identifier '__get_short_pointer'
        __p = __get_short_pointer();
              ^
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1963:40: error: use of undeclared identifier '__alloc'
        __p = __alloc_traits::allocate(__alloc(), __cap+1);
                                       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea without seeing any code, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: You need to post your code up to and including line 9.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions? @chris

Comment: Perhaps [these errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbb91f9b6803428e) are more clear. I'm not going to take a chance on which is blowing up your compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @chris!! Is there are way to fix issues that continue with this problem. I adjusted the function input statements and I was still getting the same error. I'm not sure how approach this problem do I work within the error output I'm getting? and if so, that looks like a more advanced debugging approach

Comment: does anyone have any input/suggestions that could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to anyone that tried to help!
I really appreciate it!

**I figured out the problem myself**: Turns out that vectors do not use the same logic when pulling in strings from a file as arrays do. The setup I had in my original code outputs this error because I was trying to get vectors to this way.

As an example:

Original input from file to vector:

```
for(count=0; count<teams; count++)
    getline(inputFile, names[count]);
```

Updated input from file to vector:

```
while(getline(inputFile, name))
    Teams.push_back(name);
```

Also another noted feature is that arrays by default are set as reference when being passed as parameters in a function. Vectors don't have this default feature and so required and ampersand-&-sign in either the prototype or function statement.

-Francisco

Answer (score 3):

In general, this happens a lot.

Sometimes when you reach an error, the compiler doesn't have a good way of knowing what the next symbol means. If for example, you forget a ';' then the next variable or statement doesn't make sense. The errors cascade and you'll get this sort of thing.

Other times, you'll misspell a variable definition and get an error in all the places where it is referenced.

Don't worry about the number. Worry only about the first error. Fix that and keep going one at a time. Don't let the number of problems intimidate you.